# Snowflake variable data types

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to declare a session variable to a date value but the variable keeps reading in as string or numeric.

I've tried setting the date with varying formats, with and without time, in utc format, etc but nothing has worked.  All are seen as text unless i don't use quotes or apostrophe's, in which case 2019-09-01 results in 2009 number type.

```
set(myDate)='2019-09-01'
set(myDate)="2019-09-01"
set(myDate as date)='2019-09-01'
set(myDate)='2019-09-01 18:25:53.820000000Z'
```

no matter what i try  when i run show variables it doesn't show as date or timestamp data type.  if i run `set(myDate)=current_timestamp()` that works fine but I do not want the current date.

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out so maybe this will help someone else.  When setting the variable, use to_date to cast the value at the same time.  e.g:
`set(myDate)=to_date('2019-09-01');`